# Updating counts of array based on its objects property in angular todo app

Tags: arrays, angular, angular6, counting

I am making a todos app with crud functionality in angular to learn angular6
Below in footer link there is counter of todos that are remained to complete
currently counter updates everytime with adding and removing todos, but on check and when todo is completed i dont want to count in todos left.
I am trying to find a way but i cant.
Any help will be appreciated
Thanks
Below is link of project in stackblitz:
[stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kxjnyh](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kxjnyh)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your implementation is pretty close what you are trying to do. You have method

```
public getLength(){
    this.todoService.lengthTodos();
 }
```

Which is reading the todo length from the service. You just need to return the value from service class. Make the following changes and use this function in html.

```
  public getLength(){
    return this.allTodos.filter(todo => !todo.completed).length;
  }
```

Change in the html of footer component

```
<span class="todo-count"><strong>{{getLength()}}</strong> item left</span>
```

Here is the working copy - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zqvxxb

Comment: Thanks, It worked just fine as per my question, but it stops clearCompleted to work and throws error. The problem is in isCompleted(todoService) something i am missing

Comment: Updated the link and answer - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zqvxxb

Comment: Thanks for the support